# Why can't I respond to PlayStore reviews?

Tags: android, google-play

We have a number of google app accounts associated with the developer console for our application.

Some of the accounts can reply to user reviews and some, after clicking "publish reply", get a error bar at the top of the browser window "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."

All of these accounts have full control, not just view statistics. How can I fix this so that everyone can reply to reviews.  All

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure that two same users are not online at the same time. For the accounts that you are having trouble with try this, log out all the accounts and then login with that particular account and try to reply. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

So last month Google made some updates to the dev console for play and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using double equal (`""`) and `->` text in the review comment and for some reason it was not letting me post and gave error. Even after I re-logged in, it still was giving the error. I had to remove the above symbols from my comment. Check if you have any weird symbols in your comment and try removing them. Hope this helps.